# Adonis js- Load common header footer,Internal css and Internal js to view

Tags: model-view-controller, adonis.js

I am new to Adonisjs and I am trying to load header, footer and the view file from controller in a common template and display the data from controller in the view file.

Kindly help me get through this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try use `@include('yourfolder.view')`, refer this documentation https://edge.adonisjs.com/docs/partials